# R - Column-type changes from "numeric" to “unknown” when there is only one row

Tags: r, dataframe, column-types

When I do a filter on a dataframe and the resulting dataframe has only one row, all the column-types that were "numeric" becomes "unknown".

Here is an example that you should be able to reproduce:

```
    df_test_1 <- data.frame(c(1))
    colnames(df_test_1) <- c("Column_1")
    df_test_1$Column_1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df_test_1$Column_1))

    df_test_2 <- data.frame(c(1, 2))
    colnames(df_test_2) <- c("Column_1")
    df_test_2$Column_1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df_test_2$Column_1))
```

The column-type of df_test_2 is numeric but df_test_1 is unknown

I am using R 3.5.3 with Rstudio  1.0.143

Comment: I get the class to be `numeric` in both cases on R console with `R 3.6.0`

Comment: Ditto--I can't reproduce. You mention in your question that this happens "when you do a filter"---can you show the code you use to "do a filter"? Perhaps that is needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I will try with R 3.6.0 to see if it resolve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: (FYI, I'm on R 3.5.2 still and I also get both columns as `numeric`. It's possible you have some packages loaded that mess things up? Restart R, run your code, see what the classes are... Perhaps also include the code you are using to test the class in your question. Are you comparing `class(df_test_1$Column_1)` to `class(df_test_2$Column_1)`? Make sure you spell everything correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

Update R.

Both are numeric using `class` function in R 3.6.1.

Comment: They should both be numeric in R 3.5.3 as well. I think OP either has some strange packages loaded that are messing things up or has not given a reproducible example. Or perhaps just has a typo.

Comment: I will try to be more specific: When I use the function str(df_test_1) the column is indicated as numeric but when I browse the dataframe and put the mouse cursor on the column name, it is indicated "unknown"

Comment: Maybe a visual bug. Do not worry.